# Struggling to loop through function and return proper results for Odin Project Rock, Paper, Scissors. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with making a Javascript rock, paper, scissors game from the Odin Project. I can make the basic game work, but once I attempt to call the original function in a new function and loop it, I start running into problems. My current problem is that I can get my game() function to give 5 results, but they're the same result (5 wins or 5 losses or 5 ties). I can't figure out what's wrong. At first I thought it might be because I used return after each case. After removing return until the end of playRound() I still encounter the same issue. (I currently have player choice set to rock to make it easier to track/avoid dealing with the pop-up).

I'm a beginner and still have a lot of knowledge deficiencies, so if you could explain your answers like I'm 5 that would be super appreciated.

```
/*variable declarations*/
var result = {win:0, tie:0, loss:0};
let playerChoice= "rock";
//let playerChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
const computerSelection = computerPlay();
const playerSelection = caseInsensitive();

let win = "You win";
let tie = "tie";
let loss = "You lose";

function computerPlay(){
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
 switch (a){
   case 0:
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3:
     return "rock";
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
   case 7:
     return "paper";
   default:
     return "scissors";
 }
}


function caseInsensitive(){
    return playerChoice.toLowerCase();
 }


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
let round;

 if(playerSelection==="rock"){
  switch(computerSelection){
  case "paper":
  round= loss;
  break;
  
  case "rock":
  round =tie;
  break;
   
  case "scissors":
  round= win;
  break;
  }
 }
 
  if(playerSelection=="paper"){
  switch(computerSelection){
  case "scissors":
  round= loss;
  break;
 
  case "paper":
  round = tie;
  break;
 
  case "rock":
  round = win;
  break;
  }
 }

 if(playerSelection=="scissors"){
  switch(computerSelection){
  case "rock":
  round= loss;
  break;
 
  case "scissors":
  round= tie;
  break;

  case "paper":
  round= win;
  break;
   }
  }
  return round;
 }   

function game(){
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
      if(playRound()==win){
            result.win++;
        }else if(playRound()==tie){
        result.tie++;
        }else{
        result.loss++;
    }
    }
  
  console.log("Wins: " +result.win);
  console.log("Losses: " +result.loss);
  console.log("Ties: " +result.tie);
}
game();
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're `random`ing 12 outcomes and assigning four of them to the same result? Why not just `random` 3 outcomes?

Comment: Anyway, the reason you get the same result five times is because you only ask the computer for one move - right at the start - and then use that move five times. Since the player is similarly locked to "rock", the result will always be five identical outcomes.

Comment: I was trying to get an equal amount of outcomes for rock, paper, and scissors so the probability was equal for each. It didn't even occur to me to use 3. Thank you, that'll help clear up some code.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why each loop wouldn't restart the process of requesting another move from the player and the computer. If I loop through round() 5 times, shouldn't it start the process from the beginning each time?

Comment: does the process of requesting another move is inside `playRound`? No - it's outside. Therefore, calling `playRound` as it is now, won't give you a new move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a working version of your code.  The main things to be changed were having the computer selection generated each time (so calling `computerPlay()` at the beginning of the loop) and storing the result for the round in the loop.  `playRound` without arguments does a new calculation with arguments `null` and always returns a loss.

```
/*variable declarations*/
let result = {win: 0, tie: 0, loss: 0};
let playerChoice = "rock";
//let playerChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors");

let win = "You win";
let tie = "tie";
let loss = "You lose";

function computerPlay() {
    let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    switch (a) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            return "rock";
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
            return "paper";
        default:
            return "scissors";
    }
}


function caseInsensitive() {
    return playerChoice.toLowerCase();
}


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    let round;

    if (playerSelection === "rock") {
        switch (computerSelection) {
            case "paper":
                round = loss;
                break;

            case "rock":
                round = tie;
                break;

            case "scissors":
                round = win;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (playerSelection === "paper") {
        switch (computerSelection) {
            case "scissors":
                round = loss;
                break;

            case "paper":
                round = tie;
                break;

            case "rock":
                round = win;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
        switch (computerSelection) {
            case "rock":
                round = loss;
                break;

            case "scissors":
                round = tie;
                break;

            case "paper":
                round = win;
                break;
        }
    }
    return round;
}

function game() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let playerSelection = caseInsensitive();
        let computerSelection = computerPlay();

        let roundResult = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        console.log(roundResult);
        if (roundResult === win) {
            result.win++;
        } else if (roundResult === tie) {
            result.tie++;
        } else {
            result.loss++;
        }
    }

    console.log("Wins: " + result.win);
    console.log("Losses: " + result.loss);
    console.log("Ties: " + result.tie);
}

game();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation was very helpful!